# Castle Windsor to Autofac

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, castle-windsor, autofac

I have a DevExpress example mvc web site application. It use Castle Windsor as an IOC. I just tried to replace via Autofac but no luck!

here is the sample code:

```
container
    .Register(Component
        .For<DbRepositories.ClinicalStudyContext>()
        .LifestylePerWebRequest()
        .DependsOn(new { connectionString }))
    .Register(Component
        .For<DbRepositories.IClinicalStudyContextFactory>()
        .AsFactory())
    .Register(Component
        .For<FirstStartInitializer>()
        .LifestyleTransient())
    .Register(Component
        .For<IUserRepository>()
        .ImplementedBy<DbRepositories.UserRepository>())
```

and this is my Autofac conversion:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

builder.RegisterControllers(typeof(MvcApplication).Assembly);

builder.Register(c => 
    new DbRepositories.AdminContext(connectionString))
    .InstancePerHttpRequest();

builder.RegisterType<DbRepositories.IAdminContextFactory>()
    .As<DbRepositories.IAdminContextFactory>();

builder.RegisterType<DbRepositories.UserRepository>()
    .As<IUserRepository>().InstancePerHttpRequest();
```

there is no implementetion for AsFactory() on Autofac regarding my research.

this is the `IAdminContextFactory` interface:

```
public interface IAdminContextFactory
{
    AdminContext Retrieve();
}
```

and this is the error application says:

> No constructors on type
>   'Admin.Infrastructure.EFRepository.IAdminContextFactory' can be found
>   with 'Public binding flags'.

can anyone help?

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `IAdminContextFactory` registration will fail, because the first part of the `RegisterType` must be a service type. In this case, a class that *implements* the `IAdminContextFactory` interface. Autofac tries to build an instance of the type, which certainly will fail because you cannot instantiate an interface.

So, what you need is an *implementation* of the `IAdminContextFactory` interface. The Castle `AsFactory` method generates this implementation for you. You can get this behavior with [the Autofac AggregateService](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/aggregate-services.html?highlight=AggregateService) extra.

With the bits in place you can do:

```
builder.RegisterAggregateService<IAdminContextFactory>();
```

Comment: @shortcode - Of course it works! ;) ...no really, glad to be of assistance :)

Comment: @PeterLillevold brilliant, it works like Castle Windsor Factory